# Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: No Property of name AutomationId found

Tags: xamarin

I was trying to do Xamarin UI Test on existing application. When i added following AutomationId i can't run the application and it throws following error

Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 36:14. No Property of name AutomationId found

and i can't run the test either

Your Help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AutomationId` is supported since Xamarin.Forms 2.2.0 and replaces `StyleId` for UI testing purposes. So you have to update your package.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/63983/xamarin-forms-2-2-0

Comment: When i update the package got lot of errors with Resources.cs in android project I'm building cross platform project. So if we use StyleId with old Xamarin Forms would that still work?? We are currently using 2.0.1.6505

Comment: I'm not sure if the current UI Testrunner can use StyleId. I'd guess yes, because it would break old test suites if not. Just give it a try.